# Is it possible to append some string to multiple variables all at once?

Tags: php, append, concatenation, string-concatenation

I want to append some large text, which might be modified on the future, to two multiple variables at once.

I'm trying to do it as when assigning a value to these variables but it seems that it is not possible. At least the way I try to.

Until now, the way I did it was appending both variables separately.

This is an example of my code:

```
    $var1 = $var2 = 'One ';

    $var1 .= 'Two ';

    $var2 .= 'Three ';

    //$var1 .= $var2 .= 'Four ';
    $var1 .= 'Four ';//What I do right now
    $var2 .= 'Four ';//What I do right now

    $var1 .= 'Five ';

    $var2 .= 'Six ';
```

The quoted line does not work as expected. I have tried multiple ways without success. The only working one is when I write it separately.

Comment: You need to append it separately.

Comment: True, it's duplicate. It looks like I did not search for it correctly on Google... :/